# sonarqube 6.1 issues filtering leads to 'No Issues'

Tags: sonarqube

When trying to drill down to issues - there are some of them which are 'invisible'. [[image]]

Comment: i suggest to check the web.log of sonar, if there are any exceptions, or force refresh the browser, maybe your browser is caching something odd

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a corrupt ElasticSearch index.

- stop your server
- delete $SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es
- restart your server*

<sup>* Time required for restart will vary based on the size of your instance</sup>